# Ubuntu 15.04 with Kubuntu freezes on login screen

Tags: nvidia, xorg, kubuntu, login, 15.04

I have updated to Ubuntu 15.04 with Kubuntu. But It freezes on the login screen. I cannot do anything even <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd>.

Sometimes I can log in using recovery mode but some time that also fails. It also freezes on the purple screen.

- I have tried removing xorg, reinstalling xorg server
- I have also tried removing and reinstalling nvidia
- I have also tried lightdm reconfigure
- I have also tried reinstalling ubuntu desktop

but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it myself. The problem was due to my user old profile.The old profile uses old Ubuntu settings and it has problems so I have refreshed my configuration using the steps given in [this Ubuntu Forums thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1105433). I also reinstalled `lightdm`.

Steps from the post:

> Ubuntu keeps all user settings and data in each users home folder (`/home/username`). Most of the settings files for all applications are hidden files and folders (dot files as they start with a `.` eg `.bashrc`). This makes up any user's "user profile".
>
> I simply wanted to reset my user profile to default as I had upgraded from 8.10 and wanted a clean slate with settings for 9.04 (I would copy most data/documents over etc)
>
> The easiest way would be to just create another user and use that for testing but I wanted to keep the same username. So you would think it would be easy but there are more steps than you think...
>
> Target username is `fred`
>
> 1. Create another administrator user (needs `sudo` access etc) under **Administration > Users and Groups**
> 2. Log on as that new user and go to the terminal
> 3. First back up the old profile just in case:
>
>    ```
>    sudo mv /home/fred /home/fred.old
>    ```
> 4. Create new home folder
>
>    ```
>    sudo mkdir /home/fred
>    ```
> 5. copy the skeleton (default) profile folder contents into the new folder. this gives you tab completion for bash and some other default settings etc
>
>    ```
>    sudo cp -r /etc/skel/* /home/fred
>    ```
>
>    and to copy the hidden dot files/folders
>
>    ```
>    sudo cp -r /etc/skel/.??* /home/fred
>    ```
>
>    (originally I did `sudo cp -r /etc/skel/.* /home/fred` as it made sense to me but laughed when I saw all of `/etc` (included because the glob catches `..`) in my home folder)
> 6. You don't need to do this but to move the old profile folder back into the new one for easier browsing etc do the following:
>
>    ```
>    sudo mv /home/fred.old /home/fred/
>    ```
> 7. Last we need to set the ownership and the group membership for the new folder back to `fred` so (note the capital R):
>
>    ```
>    sudo chown -R fred /home/fred
>    sudo chgrp -R fred /home/fred
>    ```
> 8. That should do it. Now log off and on to your old user and everything should be back to defaults and you should be able to browse the `fred.old` folder in your home (probably delete it after you have moved everything over)

Answer (score 0):

I've got an ASUS laptop with Nvidia Optimus GM820 and I installed Kubuntu 15.04 with Plasma 5.2 (5.3 version seems buggy in my computer, with several crashes in configuration options and others).

According to Kubuntu Drivers Settings, my nvidia recommended driver was 340.47. If I selected this choice, I got a black screen instead of my login screen. I had to press Ctrl-Alt-F1 and change the nvidia mode from nvidia to intel (`sudo prime-select intel`). After days of searching through the web, this is what I did to fix it:

- In the Drivers configuration select the nouveau driver, so I left the nvidia 340.47 driver without use.
- Reboot
- Go to Terminal and type:

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove ^nvidia
  ```

  (this erases all the files of the 340.47, or other drivers version, installed previously)
- Go to Accounts and mark autologin in your user
- Go to SDDM advanced settings an mark autologin, selecting your user (with these two configurations, you'll be able to avoid the SDDM login screen that is the guilty of the black screen)
- Reboot
- Go to Terminal and type:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install nvidia-346 nvidia-prime nvidia-settings
  sudo apt-get update
  ```

  (It's very important to install the 346 version because I wasn't able to make it work with the 340.47 version)
- Reboot

If everything goes ok, you'll be able to access your desktop directly (without the SDDM login screen) and you'll be working with the ndivia driver (type "nvidia" in the menu and the application nvidia-settings will appear, showing the working mode of your graphical card). If you run `glxgears` you'll see a very higher rate of FPS than before (with nouveau or nvidia intel mode I got 60FPS and with nvidia 346 I got 1700FPS).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the same issue as I'm on ubuntu with Unity. But here with an optimus laptop nvidia 650M with drivers 355.11 and 358.16 (and older with prime) I have a similar issue. I couldn't solve but if like me you can hear the login sound but the screen is frozen here is an ugly but simple workaround:

1. Launch sleep mode (using keyboard key or closing your laptop screen depending on your sleep mode config)
2. Recover from sleep mode

You are now back on the login screen and it's unfrozen.

The reason seams to be that nvidia drivers are not loaded on login screen or something like that.